# How to open a non-decorated fullscreen window on Ubuntu

Tags: c, unix, x11, xlib

What is the trick to open a non-decorated fullscreen window on Ubuntu? I used to change the _NET_WM_STATE property to _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN to achieve this but while working fine on KDE it doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu (GNOME; tested with 12.04 LTS). The launcher on the left and the title bar are still there and appear above my non-decorated fullscreen window which is not what I want.

When switching to fullscreen mode in Firefox, however, Firefox's fullscreen window covers the complete screen including launcher panel and title bar so it must be possible somehow to open windows that cover the entire screen, including Ubuntu's launcher and title bar.

Could anybody explain how to achieve this behaviour using plain X11 without any middleware?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. Setting _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN is not enough. One should also set the [override_redirect](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/override-redirect.html) attribute to TRUE to prevent the window manager from intercepting configure and map requests which seems to be exactly what GNOME is doing on Ubuntu by putting the launcher panel and title bar over my fullscreen window. Setting override_redirect to TRUE prevents this.

Comment: This is wrong. `override_redirect` tells X to completely bypass window management for your window. This is not what you want. If you use it, you will not have this window in your taskbar and will not be able to manage it with normal window management shortcuts/gestures.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome by default sets window max size such that it does not cover the panel. It won't resize your window beyond that size, unless you remove the corresponding hint in `WM_NORMAL_HINTS`, or set both min size and max size to your screen dimensions.

See e.g. [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/metacity-devel-list/2006-July/msg00013.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823299/mono-winforms-app-fullscreen-in-ubuntu).

This will not hurt you on KDE or any other DE either.

Remember to reset min size when you exit full screen mode.