# XLIB How to make a window go fullscreen?

Tags: c, linux, game-engine, xlib, game-development

I'm using Xlib to write my own platform library (genius plays, I know), but I can't get fullscreen to work on GNOME based DE. It works on I3 and Xfce but not on GNOME or Unity. Here is what I have so far.

```c
XSizeHints* size_hints;
long hints = 0;

size_hints = XAllocSizeHints();

if (XGetWMSizeHints(_platform.display, _window.window, size_hints, &hints,
    XInternAtom(_platform.display, "WM_SIZE_HINTS", False)) == 0) {
    puts("Failed.");
} 

XLowerWindow(_platform.display, _window.window);
XUnmapWindow(_platform.display, _window.window);
XSync(_platform.display, False);

printf("%ld\n", hints);

XFree(size_hints);

Atom atoms[2] = { XInternAtom(_platform.display, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", False), None };

XChangeProperty(
    _platform.display,
    _window.window,
    XInternAtom(_platform.display, "_NET_WM_STATE", False),
    XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*)atoms, 1);

XMapWindow(_platform.display, _window.window);
XRaiseWindow(_platform.display, _window.window);
```

Minus all of the `XGetWMSizeHints` code, this code works fine on other WMs and DEs. According to other Stack Overflow questions, the way to get fullscreen working on GNOME is to either change some `WM-NORMAL_HINT` values or remove them entirely ([How to open a non-decorated fullscreen window on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24301624/608639) and [Fullscreen window without Gnome Panel](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/GNOME/2010-01/msg00035.html)).

In order to do either I have to use `XGetWMSizeHints`, but the function is failing. Do I need to create the property for the window first, then use this function? What values should I set in `XSizeHints`?

Comment: You will likely need to ask on a Gnome related list as it probably relates to the way Gnome Desktop controls the base Xwindow. You may get a response here, but that is a fairly narrow question related to the desktop itself. You may try `gnome-list@gnome.org`

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your solution in my environment, and it works.

What I noticed though is the return value from XGetWMSizehints is 0 on failure and nonzero on success, which means your example is incorrectly printing "Failed."